# html_entity_decode() isn't working properly?

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-entities

**EDIT: I solved it seconds after posting the question (sorry!) but can't accept an answer yet.**

Hi folks,

Just a quick one. I have a PHP/CodeIgniter site and the user can edit their profile. I'm using CI's XSS Filtering and Active Record-based Models, so the data is escaped automatically.

It naturally displays fine on the profile page view, text such as *"We'll see if this works"* (the apostrophe in the *we'll*). However when the user goes to the Edit page, the input box (filled with the data in the DB) displays:

```
We&#39;ll see if this works
```

I thought I could get around it by setting the value of the input box to `html_entity_decode($query->row('example_database_row'))` but it still doesn't work. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `html_entity_decode($query->row('example_database_row'), ENT_QUOTES)`.

However, I would advise against HTML encoding before you insert it into the database. Just encode it when you output it. It's better just storing the raw data in the database.

Comment: Oh damn, that was easy. Just changed it to `html_entity_decode($query->row('example_database_row'), ENT_QUOTES)` and it works fine. Thanks anybody who read this!

Comment: Your Answer didn't work for me. I used html_entity_decode(get_the_title(), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');